# Problem in uploading app to iPhone App Store

Tags: iphone

I have build my project in iPhone sdk 3.0. I have used frameworks that is not available in iPhone sdk 2.2.1.

While they're uploading on App Store there is one option

> Choose you device type for users running in iPhone os 2.2.1 and below:
>
> option 1) iPhone only
> option 2) iPhone and iPod touch(2nd generation)
> option 3) iPhone and iPod touch

and this question is mandatory.

Have a look at following link it is screenshot of that:

http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/2509/image001fwb.jpg

The problem is my application may not run on devices which are using os version below 3.0. Which option should I go for?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to select anything other than "iPhone and iPod touch" is if you're using specific hardware capabilities unique to a particular model. If you're not, and since all touch devices support 3.0, just select "iPhone and iPod touch".